# How to create static binaries (not linked, portable) of GNU find for Solaris 8,9,10 and AIX

Tags: compilation, find, solaris, gnu, aix

We (my team) is searching for the proper method to compile the GNU find command as a static (not dynamically linked), portable binary (that I can copy from one system to another), for Solaris 8, 9 and 10.

Would anyone have a good recipe to achieve this?

We need this for several reasons, but among them the fact that we can't just pkgadd it to all the servers we need to transport it to for political and technical reasons. It's complicated, but to make it short, I support an application that uses remote agents to call system commands (called BladeLogic Server Automation). You may have seen my other posts about it, but we're having a lot of trouble on Solaris with the native find that comes with it because it's not equipped with the options we need (-path). The GNU find is, but we can't install it everywhere (would be too long and the customers owning the servers may plain refuse). NONE of the other options suggested by the community ended up working in 100% of cases on every server.

Although we can't install anything without customer approval (which can literally take weeks if not months), we CAN push a stand-alone file, execute it, and delete it afterwards if needed. Therefore, if we could just have a find binary for each Solaris and AIX platforms  we have, we would have an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

As far as Solaris is concerned, just compile in Solaris 8 and the binaries will work for 8, 9 and 10. You shouldn't link with the static C library, this goes against portability, not the other way around. A static libc is not even part of Solaris 10.

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit new to compiling actually, and I think I got the wrong idea about what static linking means then... Maybe I'm not calling it right, but what I would like is to make a self-contained binary that includes ann required libraries in it (so you are not dependant on it being present on the system). What is this called then?

Comment: What is the required library are you referring to ?

Comment: It's libintl.so.8 (See dependancies here: http://www.opencsw.org/packages/findutils/) ... which in turns is dependant on two other GNU libraries: ggettext_data and libiconv, which are not likely to be on a barebone Solaris system unless you install them too.

Comment: You can only statically link with static libraries (libfoo.a) not with dynamic libraries (libfoo.so.1).   For system libraries like libc, static linking *REDUCES* portability and greatly increases the chances your program will not work on other Solaris versions.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I'm screwed. There is just no way to can just copy a standalone 'find' binary from one system to another without the need to install the dependencies with pkgadd first?

Comment: No. You can statically link a third party library and have the binary be self contained as long as the library doesn't need itself some other files or whatever. In the GNU find particular case, you might even be able to build a binary without linking to any libintl in the first place as the functions provided by libintl are provided by Solaris libc. For example, Solaris 11 Express gnu find isn't linked with gettext. This should however be tested with Solaris 8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that findutils package has no dependencies other than libc so I dont know what do you want to statically link with it? I would expect that if you build find on one Solaris machine it should work on all. Are there any specific problems you are encountering?

Comment: Well in a particular case, the version of libc required was not present in the solaris zone I tried to copy the find binary to. It may be a question of linking it in the global zone, but we can't do this on every client server (without client approval as I explained above). The best and easiest solution for us would be to be able to simply copy a find binary where we need it without having to install or link any dependancy (even if it's only one lib).

Comment: libc must be present in your zone, otherwise no program would run. It's library that implements standard c headers and, on Linux at least standard posix headers. There is possibility that find is relying on some feature of Linux's libc not available in Solaris, thats why I asked have you tried it, and what went wrong?